# Request to rails from js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, request

I have button with link. `= link_to 'Preview', mail_templates_preview_path(mailer: @mail_template.mailer, name: @mail_template.name), id: 'some_id'` But i want add params when this button clicked. For this, i try

```
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
  url: this.href,
  type: 'GET',
  data: { template_code: $('#ckeditor').val() },
});
```

And after i expect what rails redirect me to `this.href` and render new page(../some_method.html.slim).

```
MyController
  def some_method
    @mail_template = do_something

  end
end
```

How i can to do request from js to rails controller and render this controller's page?

Comment: Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: @Niklas, no this is rails 3 and jquery 1.6

Comment: @МаксимШутков ajax will not redirect you, that's the point of ajax. If it's a link or form, you can `.submit` the event (since you prevented it), otherwise you'll need to redirect manually (e.g. `location.href = "redirect_url"`).